# GKE Cluster Node not booting

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a simple GKE cluster but the Nodes aren't booting properly due to this error: `Failed to connect to storage.googleapis.com`.

It's a private cluster and I have the NAT gateway for the network. The Node pool also uses the default compute service account which has access to everything.

Has anyone seen this error before or might know what the issue could be? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you very much :)!

Comment: Try to review your firewall rules to ensure that this node pool has access to `storage.googleapis.com` and also make sure you have not missed setting the `default-route(0.0.0.0/0)`. Lastly, please make sure that the network settings are correct. You can refer to this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cant_create_cluster_due_to_health_check_failing) for the exact steps to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you, I had missed the default route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the confirmation @salman, putting this as an answer to help others in the community.

The `Failed to connect to storage.googleapis.com` error is a common connection error on GKE Private Cluster that can be caused by wrong network configuration. Fixing this issue may include checking the firewall rules of your network or setting the configuration for the `default-route`.

For more information about this is issue you can check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cant_create_cluster_due_to_health_check_failing) and [troubleshooting steps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#to_on_prem).

Answer (score 0):

Successful node registration to a GKE cluster depends on various factors, including the following:

- Network connectivity.
- Resource availability.
- Service account permissions.

When GKE creates a node for your cluster, the initial step involves creating a new Compute Engine VM instance.

Instance creation might fail due to one of the following reasons:

Insufficient quota
Resource availability
Insufficient IP address space

In your situation, the error message suggests that the VM instance failed to download the necessary packages to prepare for running as a GKE node, possibly due to a connection timeout. This indicates that your cluster may not have fulfilled the networking requirements essential for connecting to Google APIs and services, such as storage.googleapis.com.

Depending on your network configuration, enabling this connection may involve configuring Private Google Access or setting up firewall rules and routes within your cluster's Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network to permit the connection.